# ラズパイ3でvmlinuxを使いたい。

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, kernel

## 現在の状況

raspberrypi3 modelBでlibbpfを使いたく環境構築を行っています。

しかし、

```
bpftool btf dump file /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux format c > vmlinux.h
```

とすると、パスのエラーが出たので、確認すると /sys/kernel以降がありませんでした。
調べたところ、

```
~/linux$ grep -E "(BPF|BTF)[_= ]" /boot/config-$(uname -r)


# CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF is not set
```

となっており、[Build kernel with /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux enabled](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=349411)によると、

```
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=y
```

と.configで書き換えればい良いとのことでした。

## やったこと

[Raspberry Pi Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html)を基に、カーネルをダウンロードして、make bcm2711_defconfigまでを行いました。
その後、.config内で、CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTFを探したところ、一致する行が無いといわれました。

## 知りたいこと

CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=yにする方法。

もしくは、他の方法でvmlinuxを利用できるようにする方法。

## 現在の環境

```
uname -a
Linux Raspberrypi 6.2.0-1004-raspi #5-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 11:15:14 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: 単純に有効化するだけなら
`echo "CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=y" >> .config` で可能だけどそれでビルドできるかどうかは不明(未確認)

Comment: それでいいんですかね、、、

とりあえず、やってみます！　ありがとうございます。

Comment: うまくできなかったです。。。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 解決方法

wsl上で行うと、SDカード内がきちんと認識されませんでした。
実機で行うと、document通りに動かすことができました。